# How to make letters line up in word-wrap?

Tags: html, css

This was the best way  I thought of making vertical text.

How do I make the leters "ello" line up with "h"?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxaoaw

```
<p>Hello</p>

p {
width: 0.5em;
font-size: 5em;
word-wrap: break-word;  
}
```

Comment: the small width makes it so there is 1 letter on each line which is what I want. increasing the width doesnt break the letters .

Comment: @Pathway, your width is too small to contain your 5em letters. The first letter "H" is actually sticking outside of your `p` element and that's why you won't be able to center the letters vertically with your current code. If you set `overflow: hidden` to your `p` element, you'll see that the half of the letter "H" will disappear, in order words, it will be hidden because half of it is outside of your `p` element. In order to center your letters vertically, they all have to share the same width.

Comment: Depending on the font, 0.5em is too wide: it will cause the two `l`s to end up on the same line. Or is that by design?

Answer (score 1):

You have a width set to the paragraph tag, add text align center and add a width a little higher than 0.5em.

```css
p {
width: 0.7em;
font-size: 5em;
word-wrap: break-word;
text-align: center;
letter-spacing: 7px;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
```

Is this what you were after?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to align the characters with letter 'H' then bellow approach will do. `text-align: center;` will center the characters to its allocated space.

```css
p {
  width: 0.5em;
  font-size: 5em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
```

More information about `text-align` property can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-align).

Answer (score 0):

Try the code as below

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

css code

```
p {
  width: 0.5em;
  font-size: 5em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/97odgsgr/)

Answer (score 0):

This depends upon your font selection.

Check the Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/97odgsgr/1/

```
p {
width: 0.5em;
font-size: 5em;
text-align: center;
word-break: break-all;
}
```